# How can I learn more about my father, who was born in Spain and lived in Morocco?

Tags: 20th-century, spain, morocco

My father was born in La Linea, Spain. He said he played football for Morocco and also was married there. He spent many years in Morocco in the 1940's. How can I learn more about him?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Genealogy.SE. Did you lose contact to your father or why are no biographical details known to you? Do you have any records like birth and death certificate, documents concerning the marriage. What sources have you checked so far, e.g. newspapers, are there relatives to contact?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Genealogy.SE! Per the [help center](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), if the individual is potentially living, please refrain from including personally identifying details to protect privacy. General questions about research techniques on recent ancestors are OK, though.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/how-can-i-access-records-from-morocco/ (which does however focus on the French administered areas, rather than the Spanish).

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to investigate.

By the time your father was born, almost all citizens were baptised in Spain. Catholic Church is keeping an strong record of baptism and all related sacraments in the faith.

That means:

- If you know the church and the baptism date you will be able to find the church he was baptised. If you get the record of the baptism you will have information about a previous place he lived and some relatives (godfather and godmother)
- Not having the date of baptism of the specific church will require to go church by church in la Linea.
- If your father kept the catholic faith and married in Marocco in catholic faith you can also contact the church where he married (there are very few!!!), that will have a tracked record towards the baptism place. You will also get another living relatives, witness and another address.

Concerning spanish registries:

- When your father moved to the country he has been living, that country should have communicated the change of country to spanish authorities. There should be specific information about birth registry in Spain.
- With that information you can request [spanish registry](http://www.mjusticia.gob.es/cs/Satellite/es/1200666550200/Tramite_C/1214483947232/Detalle.html) to provide you the birth registry information and any related civil information (marriage). Also you will be able to track your granparents.

With that information you will be able to explore descendants and previous living places.

Comment: Morocco annexed many formerly spanish territories, so his father didn't necessarily immigrate from a country to another.

Comment: @bregalad Rif (Spanish Marocco) was a protectorate not an integral part of Spain. They had their own administration. So he should have immigrated to a different administration. However based on the question made, I understood that her father immigrated afterwards to another different country, that will be another immigration data to use